# Angular2 Authguard for user login

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

So I have the backend setup such that if I POST login, then it starts a session and if I POST logout, it ends that session.
I want to write Angular2 auth guard such that it keeps track of if the user is logged in or not.

//login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    questions: any[]; 
    error_message: string = 'Login Unsuccessful'

  constructor(public router: Router, 
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, 
    question_service: LoginQuestionService) {

    this.questions = question_service.getQuestions(); 
    this.authenticationService.logged_in.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log("Login Status: " + value);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  formSubmitted(data): void {
    this.login(data.username, data.password);
  }


  login(username, password) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.authenticationService.login(username, password)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.authenticationService.logged_in.next(true);
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      },
      error => {
        this.authenticationService.logged_in.next(false);
        alert(this.error_message);
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        console.log(error);
      }
      );
  };
```

//authenticationservice.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {    
    private base_url: string;
    public logged_in: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
     
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.base_url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    }

    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<Response> {
        let query_url = `${this.base_url}login`;
        let payload = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
        return this.http.post(query_url, payload)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

    logout(): Observable<Response>{
        let query_url = `${this.base_url}logout`;
        return this.http.post(query_url, null);
    }
}
```

How would go about writing an auth guard that keeps track of the variable in the service?
What is the best way to keep track of login? I know in AngularJS, there is $rootscope variable but not in Angular2

Comment: You should use JWT-tokens as @crash states. It's a quick and safe method for checking whether a user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a lot to handle in SO.

I suggest to have a look at this module https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt to handle jwt tokens and authentication in general.

Comment: I don't think that will help tho. I am talking about all frontend work

Comment: I know, I used it here if you want to have a look at it: https://github.com/damnko/angular2-django-movies. Are you familiar with jwt tokens?  Otherwise you can simply create an observable/subject in your authenticationservice to keep track of the login status. But I don't think it's the best approach